# React Native Android app builds as RNOneSignalAndroid instead of my app

Tags: android, react-native, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

My app has the wrong app name and opens to the wrong activity, instead of my main activity it opens the OneSignal activity.

OneSignal is a service I'm using for notifications.

What can I do to use the MainActivity instead?

[image: my app with the wrong app name]

`MainActivity.java`:

```java
package com.social.firebase.example.socializus;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import expo.modules.ReactActivityDelegateWrapper;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "main";
  }
}
```

`MainApplication.java`:

```java
package com.social.firebase.example.socializus;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import expo.modules.ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher;
import expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapper;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHostWrapper(
    this,
    new ReactNativeHost(this) {
      @Override
      public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
      }

      @Override
      protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
        List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
        return packages;
      }

      @Override
      protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
        return "index";
      }
    }
  );

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, false);
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onApplicationCreate(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onConfigurationChanged(this, newConfig);
  }

  private static void initializeFlipper(
    Context context,
    ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager
  ) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName(
          "com.social.firebase.example.socializus.ReactNativeFlipper"
        );
        aClass
          .getMethod(
            "initializeFlipper",
            Context.class,
            ReactInstanceManager.class
          )
          .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the App name in String.xml file.

Comment: The app name in strings.xml is correct, it’s just not launching the correct activity and showing the incorrect activity app name